# Notify user about a new app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

1. suppose, user has installed my app1. and after someday i have
   developed a new app2. now i want to notify app1 user about my new
   app2 in the notification bar. i want to notify my user about my new
   app2 from my server. how can i do it? i have read about GCM, but i
   cannot understand it.

   [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)
2. beside GCM i am thinking about another way. i can use an alarm which
   will knock my server and if it find any notification then it will
   show that in the notification bar. is this a good practice ?
3. think that user have also installed app2. if so, i don't want to
   show the notification about app2. how can i do that?
4. can i also notify user about an update of already installed app? if
   user click the notification, then i want to take user to Google
   play.

any tutorial or blog or discussion will be very helpful.
and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can integrate GCM for push notifications in all your apps, and send a notification whenever you have a new app or update available. You say you don't understand it, but you don't say what you don't understand. Try going through the documentation and examples and third party tutorials
2. Using a notification to tell the user is a good practice. Using an alarm to poll your server is good practice, as long as you don't do it very often. Doing this too much will affect user battery life.
3. Before you show the notification, you can use the PackageManager to check if your app has been installed already.
4. Google Play does not allow your app to check for updates, but you can once again use GCM to send a notification to the app after you've uploaded an update. After that, you can simply launch the app's page in Google Play using.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: suppose, user have installed app but currently not using the app. and in the mean time i have pushed a notification. will GCM show the notification in the notification bar? @Raghav Sood

Comment: @Shoshi Assuming your app was opened by the user at least once, it will receive GCM notifications. Whether you want to display them in the notification bar or not is upto you.

Answer (score 0):

[Check for updates](http://www.androidsnippets.com/check-for-updates-once-a-day) This code snippet will help you for sure. It checks once in days time for any update. Check and ping me back if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM)
Here is an C2dM documentation. It's in the form of a tutorial and it both explains how everything works, and provides sample code.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

here is an another tutorial!
Android push-notifications using Google cloud messaging gcm php and mysql
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: C2DM is now deprecated and has been replaced by GCM